# Run an Excel macro if cell "A500" gets visible / on screen

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to get an Excel macro running as soon as cell "A500"
becomes visible on the screen when scrolling down/up the worksheet.

I remember reading somewhere about an active-x or standard control
that has an "on scrolling into view" event, so this could be done
by placing a control directly on the worksheet near the desired cell.
Finding this control currently eludes me.

A better way of course would be a cell formula, subclassing still is
a bad idea in the long run i guess :)

```
Sub temp_01() 'Excel Vba

'user scrolls down from cell "A1"

'when the user reaches cell "A500" show the following message:
MsgBox "Chapter 2"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the code you are working on to solve this in your question and explain the problems you are having with it.

Comment: Question also is how often should the macro run. If you scroll up and down what should happen if A500 becomes visible again. And what should happen when you scroll and A500 stays visible?

Comment: The event should fire once every time cell "A500" gets scrolled into the Excel viewport. If cell "A500" gets scrolled out or already is visible and the user scrolls again the event should not fire.

Comment: Check out the [Window.VisibleRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.visiblerange) property

Comment: For my usage "Window.VisibleRange" would additionally require hooking the scrollwheel i think, which is subclassing and most likely not stable enough in the long run.

Comment: You could use the CommandBarsOnUpdate event to "catch" scrolling through the scrollwheel, (clicking the scrollbars does not fire this event)

Comment: Looks promising, i'll check it out... thoroughly :)

Comment: It's "CommandBars.OnUpdate" event (for Office) actually, slight difference there.

Comment: Missed the . dot, I'll post an example

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, with the help of the Onupdate event, (catches the mousewheel, not clicking on the scrollbars) (Change Sheetname(s) and Range(s) to yours)

In Class called ClsMonitorOnupdate:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objCommandBars As Office.CommandBars
Private rMonitor As Range
Private scrol As Boolean

Public Property Set Range(ByRef r As Range): Set rMonitor = r: End Property

Public Property Get Range() As Range: Set Range = rMonitor: End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objCommandBars = Application.CommandBars
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set objCommandBars = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objCommandBars_OnUpdate()
Dim myrng As Range
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> rMonitor.Parent.Name Then Exit Sub
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Selection, rMonitor) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set myrng = Application.Intersect(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange, ActiveSheet.Range("a500"))

    If Not myrng Is Nothing And Not scrol Then scrol = True: MsgBox "chapter"
    If myrng Is Nothing And scrol Then scrol = False

 End Sub
```

In the ThisWorkbook section:

```
Option Explicit
Private sRanges As String
Private cMonitor As ClsMonitorOnupdate

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set cMonitor = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Zetaan ActiveSheet
End Sub
Sub Zetuit()
 Set cMonitor = Nothing
End Sub
Sub Zetaan(sht As Worksheet)
    Select Case sht.Name
        Case "Sheet1": sRanges = "A1:ZZ1000"
        Case "Other Sheet": sRanges = "A1:ZZ1000"
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select
     Set cMonitor = New ClsMonitorOnupdate
    Set cMonitor.Range = Sheets(sht.Name).Range(sRanges)
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Zetaan Sh
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Set cMonitor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good, i'll work on this with the addition of a timer/listener "Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial( 0 ,  0 ,  0 )" event together with "ActiveWindow.VisibleRange" to also catch scrolling done with mouse clicks/dragging on the scrollbar. Downside for the timer is that the Vbe stop/reset button also stops the timer. Would be neat if someone has an idea how to have a better timer. Or maybe i'll ask in another question.